# jQuery toggle alternative way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since toggle is deprecated I used this to toogle div:

```
$("#syndicates_showmore").on("click", function () {

    if (!clicked) {
        $('#syndicates').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function () {
            $(this).css(
            {
                'height': 'auto',
                'overflow': 'none'
            });
        }).fadeTo('slow', 1);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#syndicates_showmore").text("Show less");
        }, 500);

        clicked = true;
    }
    else {
        $('#syndicates').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function () {
            $(this).css(
            {
                'height': '290px',
                'overflow': 'hidden'
            });
        }).fadeTo('slow', 1);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#syndicates_showmore").text("Show more");
        }, 500);

        clicked = false;
    }
});
```

Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Comment: could be shortened by only creating the paremters for each condition and calling the animation and timer once. But that's just housecleaning a bit of DRY

Comment: what makes you think .toggle() is deprecated?
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @AshleyMedway there used to be 2 toggle methods in API.... one was a convenience for 2 clicks like off and on. It tracked 1st and second clcik and called one of 2 callbacks for arguments

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: John, I have added an example for you, with different animation effects, which you could easily adapt to your code. Tell me more if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed):

> **.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed**
>
> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions" signature of `.toggle()`. It should not be confused with the "change the visibility of an element" of `.toggle()` which is not deprecated. The former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used to restore the functionality.

In other words, you can still use `.toggle` like this:

```
var clicked = false;
$("#syndicates_showmore").on("click", function () {
    clicked = !clicked;
    var showText = "Show " + (clicked ? "more" : "less");
    $('#syndicates').toggle(function () {
        $("#syndicates_showmore").text(showText);
    });
});
```

Comment: you have the 2 backwards based on what OP was referring to. Notice OP has 2 condisions for clcik...which is what the deprecated `toggle` did

Comment: there ya go...DRY it out baby

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative is to use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass):

```
$("#syndicates_showmore").on("click", function () {
    $('#syndicates').toggleClass("newClass, 1000", "easeInOutBounce")
});
```

*[jQuery .toggleClass() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)*:

> **Description:** Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's
>   presence or the value of the switch argument.

If using with [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) you can easily animate it with using different easing options.

*[Easings:](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)*

> Easing functions specify the speed at which an animation progresses at
>   different points within the animation. jQuery UI provides several additional
>   easing functions, ranging from variations on the swing behavior to
>   customized effects such as bouncing.

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/XHkGL/)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$("#clickme" ).click(function() {
   $( "#book" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });
});
```